# Azure webapp "Certificate with thumbprint 'XXXXXX...' not found" error

Tags: azure, ssl, web-applications

I'm having the following issue with one of my webapps at Azure. It was working fine and suddenly I'm getting the following error, even though no changes were made to the webapps:

> "Certificate with thumbprint 'XXXX' not found at
>   APP.Security.CertificateEncryptionServiceProvider.FindCertificate(X509Store
>   certStore, String thumbprint) at
>   APP.Security.CertificateEncryptionServiceProvider.Decrypt(String
>   thumbprint, String encryptedSetting) at
>   APP.Configuration.CloudConfiguration.GetSetting"

The other web apps who are using the same certificates are working perfectly fine.

When I navigate to the KUDU powershell console *https://MyAppThatHasProblems.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell* and navigate to the Certificate Store

```
cd cert:/currentuser/my
```

I cannot see any certificate. If I do the same for any other working web app I can see my certificates listed. I tried to remove and add again the certificates, but no luck.

Anyone had a similar issue before?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve the issue with the help of Azure Support. After a series of investigations on the app service they told me to **scale up from S2 Standard to S3 Standard and then back to S2**. Apparently this changes the virtual machine where the app service is hosted.

Problem fixed!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I scaled up from P2 to P3 and back down to P2 and still no certificate. Is this all that happened, or did Azure support fix something in backend?

Comment: They told me to scale up from S2 Standard to S3 Standard and then back to S2, and after all was fine, I don't know if they made other changes. I think you have to raise a ticket for this issue.

Comment: It really sucks that the best Azure's official support channel can come up with was essentially the cloud equivalent of "have you restarted your computer", but can also vouch for it working in my instance.